# How to implement Binary Indexed Tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have read that Binary Indexed Trees are very efficient. But I couldn't anything more than that. If anybody knows about that, please share your knowledge.

Comment: This question is not very well suited for SO. Have a look at [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: There is no such thing as a data structure that is "efficient", without specifying the task. A data structure may be ideal for some set of tasks, but there will be other tasks for which it is unacceptable, and another data structure ideal. What are you trying to accomplish? Why do you think a binary indexed tree would be appropriate for that job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [solution](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) will help you. There are direct algorithms available and this explanation is a good one I could see

This is how the author of the blog has described Binary indexed Tree

We often need some sort of data structure to make our algorithms faster. In this article we will discuss the Binary Indexed Trees structure. According to Peter M. Fenwick, this structure was first used for data compression. Now it is often used for storing frequencies and manipulating cumulative frequency tables.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @kiamlaluno sure I am doing that :)